# My dynamic site is not loading when the site is online but works well in localhost

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm getting this error when my site is online

> [host www.sitename.com] Backend fatal error: PHP Fatal error:  require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required 'admin/config/connection.php' (include_path='.:/opt/cpanel/ea-php53/root/usr/share/pear:/opt/cpanel/ea-php53/root/usr/share/php') in /home/mistrybu/public_html/index.php on line 373\n

The site works well in localhost but when its put online , the dynamic part is not showing.

I changed the php version from php7 to php5 in cpanel. Now the front end is working but the backend is not.

Can someone help me solve this error?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: _"I changed the php version from php7 to php5"_ - You should rather make sure the code works with PHP 7 instead of downgrading PHP to an old and unsupported version.

Comment: "I changed the php version from php7 to php5 in cpanel." — PHP5 is no longer supported and doesn't receive security updates. Don't do that.

Comment: i did my code in php5.

Comment: Then you should update your code to work with PHP 7.

Answer (score 1):

**PHP version**

Definitely do not go back to PHP5. Keep it to 7. If that means rewriting some of the existing code, so be it, it will make your site more secure and more future proof.

## Error Message

Your `require_once()` method cannot find or access a particular file. This is most probably because:

**File missing**

The file (`connection.php`) doesn't exist in the given location (`admin/config`). Now keep in mind that as the location doesn't start with a `/`, it's going to be relative to where the `require_once()` method is being run from.

Since you're running `require_once()` from:

`home/mistrybu/public_html/`

it's going to look for the file here:

`/home/mistrybu/public_html/admin/config/`.

Does that location exist? Does the `connection.php` reside in the folder?

**Folder mismatch**

Try adding the following prefix to your path, and see if that makes a difference:

`require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/admin/config/connection.php';`

**File errors**

Maybe the file exists, but for some reason, gives an error. Try running the following from your command line and see if you get any errors:

`php -f admin/config/connection.php`

Comment: yes it exists. and also it works well in localhost. The dynamic part in the front end is also working. Only backend is not working.

Comment: I added some additional things to try. See if any of them help.

Comment: Same error? what if you just _run_ the connection.php file, do you get any errors?